# Error at Derived column in SSIS package due to invalid date format. how to skip such value?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am importing CSV files from a folder which is generated by another application.
While importing using SSIS package in some CSV files instead of date format decimal value are coming how to skip such values while processing in Derived column to avoid error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the error output of the Derived column transformation to redirect such rows to either a flat file or a table of your choice.